# How do you debug a BST verification algorithm in Haskell?

Tags: algorithm, haskell, binary-search-tree

I'm trying to write a verification algorithm that a tree satisfies the BST property, and am asking about a bug in my code.

```
data Tree x = Leaf x | Node x (Tree x) (Tree x)
  deriving (Show)

window :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Bool
window min max x = min <= x && x <= max 

bstHelper :: Int -> Int -> Tree Int -> Bool
bstHelper min max (Leaf x) = window min max x
bstHelper min max (Node x t1 t2) = (window min max x) && (bstHelper min x t1) && (bstHelper x max t1)

x1 = bstHelper 3 6 (Node 5 (Leaf 3) (Leaf 6))
x2 = (window 3 6 5) && (bstHelper 3 5 (Leaf 3)) && (bstHelper 5 6 (Leaf 6)) 

wrong = x1 == x2
```

Why is wrong false?
How would you personally debug this?

Comment: You used `t1`, not `t2`, as the last argument to `bstHelper` in the second recursive call.

Comment: Enable warnings, it will report the unused `t2`. Strongly recommended.

Comment: It might help to compile with `-Wall`. The GHC compiler can check a certain number of things, and often can warn you about "strange" elements in your code.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to fixing your code is in the comments below your question, use `t2` in the last part: `(bstHelper max x t2)`. If you compile with `-Wall` it would probably tell you that you have an unused parameter `t2`. If you name a value in Haskell and do not use it, the compiler will complain. If you want to name a value and not use it, then you should prefix the name with `_`.

Finally, a few tips for how to approach debugging in Haskell. If it is compiling and there are non warnings, load it into GHCi and `bstHelper` on a few examples to see if it works as you expect. Then the next step is to setup tests, take a look at these libraries: `hspec` a testing library (with just this you can do unit testing), `QuickCheck` helps you generate arbitrary (fuzzed) data to test the properties of a program (property testing).